# Which languages (and target names) does genmsg support?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, genmsg, generate-messages, add-message-files

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The documentation for [`genmsg`](https://github.com/ros/genmsg) seems to indicate that generated targets follow language-name conventions.

> E.g. if you target foo depends on the C++ messages of your current bar project, you need to add:
> `add_dependencies(foo bar_gencpp)`

--- https://docs.ros.org/api/genmsg/html/usermacros.html

Is there a list of these supported languages? Is there documentation explaining how the `genmsg` cmake macros generate target names?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319505/which-languages-(and-target-names)-does-genmsg-support?/) by [rubicks](https://answers.ros.org/users/38175/rubicks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 193 on 2019-03-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Collecting relevant comments from the answer from @janindu :

> This loop in `genmsg` invokes all available generators which are on their own create their targets: https://github.com/ros/genmsg/blob/f9dad2f897fc9bafec038ed8a74986ba766e9e9d/cmake/pkg-genmsg.cmake.em#L86-L132

--- [dirk-thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/)

> Generators essentially register as plugins against `genmsg` using a `message_generator` tag in the `export` section of their manifests.

--- [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/)

With regard to the enumeration of packages that provide language generators, this is entirely dependent on which packages are present; for most catkin workspaces, this is a function `rosdep` and any `package.xml` files present.

However, for the *common case* where a given project depends on the `message_generation` package, the following generators are dependencies thereof and guaranteed to be present:

- https://wiki.ros.org/gencpp
- https://wiki.ros.org/geneus
- https://wiki.ros.org/genlisp
- https://wiki.ros.org/gennodejs
- https://wiki.ros.org/genpy

In this case, the `generate_messages` macro provided by `genmsg` will understand (eponymous) `LANGS` option arguments for each of these five generators.

References:

- https://wiki.ros.org/message_generation?distro=kinetic
- https://wiki.ros.org/message_generation?distro=lunar
- https://wiki.ros.org/message_generation?distro=melodic

Much thanks to @janindu, @gvdhoorn, and @dirk-thomas for all your help.

---

Originally posted by [rubicks](https://answers.ros.org/users/38175/rubicks/) with karma: 193 on 2019-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0